# escaping double quotes in batch script that creates VB script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, escaping

I have a batch script that is supposed to create a VB script that is supposed to create a shortcut. The problem is that the shortcut has a parameter that uses a double quote and I can't get it to work. Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\ShortcutName.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fix.bat"" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory ="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
```

The target for the shortcut is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fix.bat"
```

I tried escaping it with ^ and \ and tried single quotes and double double quotes but then I think that breaks the VB script. I think it might be because the target doesn't have any quotes to start but the VB script needs them. I dunno. Any ideas?

Comment: there is a propery called `oLink.Agruments` to which the `/C "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fix.bat"` portion must be passed; hence `oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"`;

Comment: Ugh. Thanks. Sorry for the duplicate. I really tried looking before I posted, but I was focused on the batch part and didn't think about the VB side.